# Xcode 6.3 beta - Your executable contains unsupported architecture '[armv7k]'

Tags: ios, xcode, arm, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I'm updating my existing app to include support for Apple Watch (at this stage just handling of notifications), however when I archive my app and try to submit it to the app store for review I continually get this error.

I've tried playing around with the build settings and I've also tried googling the error, however I can't figure out what the issue is.

Does anyone have any ideas or has anyone come across this issue too?

[image]

Comment: Same problem using xCode 6.2 beta. The error also appears when only validating. Maybe the validation simply does not accept watchkit apps yet.

Comment: Still not working after iOS 8.2 and xCode 6.2 are released. Maybe iTunes Connect needs some time. I'll have to try it again tomorrow

Comment: Your question has been answered in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929034/xcode-unsupported-architecture-armv7k

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit an app for review using a beta version of Xcode.

Following today's Apple Watch official release, Apple updated Xcode to version 6.2 which in theory should allow submitting apps that contain Watch extensions. However I just tried to submit my app  that includes support for Watch using the new Xcode, and got the same error. I hope this will be fixed sometime soon on the ItunesConnect site.