# Xcode unsupported architecture armv7k

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When trying to validate my new app using watchkit with xcode 6.2 I get a strange error:

> iTunes Store operation failed.
>   Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[armv7k]'.

What does armv7k even mean? 
All my build settings (for the app and all extensions) look like the ones in the following screenshot:
[image: build settings]
Could the red color of my embedded binaries have something to do with the problem? Everything works great on my device and on the simulators.
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Update:
xCode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 was released. Problem is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more than likely not passing validation as you can't actually submit watch apps yet.

Per https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/:

> Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not accepted at this time.

Comment: Thank you now we know whats going on :) Must have missed that

Comment: Pretty easy to miss since its the only official place anywhere that says this. Once 8.2 went live I was under the assumption we could submit too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is architecture of new Apple Watch. It is not architecture of your main app so you can't see it in build settings of your app. For sure it is impossible to submit app from Xcode beta.

I have the same issue but from Xcode 6.2 (not beta). May be itunesconnect does't support watchkit extensions yet.

Comment: Yep I think so too. Don't understand why they would not allow watchkit apps yet.